# Rails Delegate Set Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a User.rb model and a UserSetting.rb model that i would like to delegate to (both getter and setter methods).

in user.rb

```
delegate :email_opt_in, :email_opt_in=, :to => :user_setting
```

At first glance this works great.

```
user = User.find(1)
user.email_opt_in #=> false
user.email_opt_in = true
user.save
user.email_opt_in #=> true
```

But looking closer the, `user.save` doesn't propagate to the UserSetting model.

```
User.find(1).email_opt_in #=> false
```

(So the value didn't get saved to the database).

This is my question: How can I get UserSetting to save automatically when one of its attributes are changed and then saved by its user?

This should only happen when a UserSetting attribute is changed otherwise every time a user is saved to the database it will trigger an additional un-needed & unwanted write to the database.

Comment: Does changes always go through forms? That way one can use accepts_nested_attributes with fields_for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would explore using an [ActiveRecord callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) for this. I'm not sure which would make the most sense in your case, but `before_update` or `after_update` seem logical. In your callback, you would need to manually trigger a save call on the UserSetting object associated with the User. There's probably dozens of ways to accomplish this, but something along these lines should work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update do |user|
    user.user_setting.save if user.user_setting.changed?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 24):

In your User model for user_setting association use autosave: true

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_setting, autosave: true

  delegate :email_opt_in, :email_opt_in=, :to => :user_setting
end
```

Comment: Wow! Perfect. This answer should be promoted to the correct one.